# FME issue, deleting row based cell value

Tags: python, fme, simpletransformers

Hell all, so let try to describe my problem in the best light possible. I have experience with Python but have never used FME. I would like to delete a full row of data based on criteria in a particular column.

I have an idea of how I would write this in Python but being new to FME not quiet sure where I start here with the transformations.. For example: the Column will have an A, B, or C. If the column for any row has a "C" I want to to delete this full row. While it seems simple enough Python I'm not quite sure where to start with FME. Any help or helpful tips to point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "tester" transformer, add you're conditions in the transformer. You'll have 2 output ports, the first one (passed) is the data matching the conditions, the second (failed) not matching, that it.

(google translate from french)